# Recovering closed AMQP channel on RabbitMQ client (Java)

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

Could anyone provide suggestions on how to recover from a closed AMQP channel.

Scenario:

When the broker (Apache Qpid - 0.22) receives a messages with unknown exchange name it closes the producer for the messages as a result channel on the client side (RabbitMQ) gets closed. 
I would like to recover the closed channel on Amqp client, what is the correct approach to accomplish this.

I had tried wrapping channel reference and on receiving a shutdownCompleted event I try to create a new channel and assign the reference to the channel within the wrapper, by a separate thread.

However, this approach seems to have issue when allocating new auto recoverable channel.

Is there any other way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Are you sure that client and server have the same amqp implementation? Rabbitmq has supported amqp 0.9.1 ...

Comment: yes, I have even tried Lyra.